# NetworkOnMainThreadException on Runnable

Tags: android, runnable, networkonmainthread

I am making Android 4.4 project. I've got `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. 
Below is my process.

```
Service(sticky) -> Handler(per 5 minutes) -> Runnable -> HttpPost
```

Isn't Runnable a separate thread? Shoud I use AsyncTask in Runnable?

Comment: You might consider reading the documentation? `http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html`

Comment: Off the cuff, it sounds like you should be replacing the sticky service and `Handler` with `AlarmManager` and an `IntentService`, perhaps my `WakefulIntentService`. Don't waste the user's RAM with a service that hangs around just watching the clock tick. As a side benefit, `IntentService`'s `onHandleIntent()` runs on a background thread.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Runnable is a simple interface, that, [as per the Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html), "*should be implemented* by any class whose instances are *intended to be executed by a thread*." (Emphasis mine.)

For instance, defining a Runnable as follows will simply execute it in the same thread as it's created:

```
new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d("Runnable", "Hello, world!");
    }
}.run();
```

Observe that all you're actually doing here is creating a class and executing its public method `run()`. There's no magic here that makes it run in a separate thread. Of course there isn't; Runnable is just an [interface of three lines of code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/lang/Runnable.java)!

Compare this to implementing a Thread (which implements Runnable):

```
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d("Runnable", "Hello, world!");
    }
}.start();
```

The primary difference here is that Thread's `start()` method takes care of the logic for spawning a new thread and executing the Runnable's `run()` inside it.

Android's AsyncTask further facilitates thread execution and callbacks onto the main thread, but the concept is the same.

Answer (score 4):

`Runnable` just per se is **not** a `Thread`. You can use a `Runnable` to be run inside a `Thread`, but these are different concepts. You can use an `AsyncTask` or just define a `Thread` and use `.start()` over it.