# NetworkOnMainThreadException in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want to perform network operation in other class. I have created a `Runnable` in `MainActivity` but I am having the exception `NetworkOnMainThreadException`

My question is do Runnable is not creating another thread from UI thread?
I am new to Android development.

**MainActivity.java**

```
 //Inside MainActivity Class
//.....
Runnable initStack = new Runnable(){
   @Override 
   public void run(){
      otherClassObject.itsMethod();
      handler.post(new Runnable(){
             //back to UI thread.... 
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: where is your network call?

Comment: you should be using an `AsyncTask`

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is do Runnable is not creating another thread from UI thread?

No. A `Runnable` is not a `Thread`. If you want a `Thread`, use a `Thread`, or use something else that uses a `Thread` (e.g., `AsyncTask`).

Comment: Ok.. Got it. Thank  you. I ask this question because I found tutorial about handler, they implement like above code(my code); Explaining handler class etc.

Comment: @mubeen: By default, a `Handler` is tied to the main application thread, and `post()` will trigger a call to `run()` on the `Runnable` on the main application thread. You can specifically create a `HandlerThread` to have a `Handler` that is not associated with the main application thread, but this is an advanced technique and not one that many Android developers use. Usually, Android developers will use `AsyncTask`, `IntentService`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new Thread, not only a runnable. Instead of calling `initStack.run()`, do the following: `new Thread(initStack).start();`

Answer (score 1):

possible duplicate of: [NetworkOnMainThreadException on Runnable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22580354/networkonmainthreadexception-on-runnable)

According to java documentation, "should be implemented by any class whose instances are intended to be executed by a thread."

In a nutshell, Android has made some changes to handling of network related thread on the main thread. It is done by AsyncTask.

Read about it here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Also, it would be better if you would go through the basics of Android programming and some tutorials before you take a leap of faith into the actual coding part.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to. Runnable is donot create thread. Runnable is simple three lines interface.

```
new Thread() {
            @Override
           public void run() {
               //your code here
           }
       }.start();
```